# Check if point is in rectangle

Tags: go

I have an `image.Point` and an `image.Rectangle`.  I'd like to know how to check if the point is in the rectangle.  I know that I can manually check with:

```
p := image.Point{}
r := image.Rect{}

if r.Min.X <= p.X && p.X < r.Max.X && r.Min.Y <= p.Y && p.Y < r.Max.Y {
    // Point is in the rectangle!
}
```

But that is a pain!  Is there a better way to do this?  I can't find a `Contains()` in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Rectangle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It’s on `Point`, not `Rectangle`:](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Point.In)

```
if p.In(r) {
    …
}
```